# WordPress - How to add class to top level nav links only

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to create the following menu in WordPress:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-active">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Link</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu other_dropdwn">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Link</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu other_dropdwn">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Link</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```

So far this is what I've come up with...

The menu itself embedded in my header.php

```
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
    'menu' => 'primary-menu',
    'container' => false,
    'container_class' => false,
    'container_id' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'menu_id' => false,
    'depth' => 0,));
?>
```

My `functions.php` page

```
//Load Custom Menu Navigation
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
        )
    );
}

//Clean up Custom Menu by Removing Unecessary Tags
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1 );
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1 );
add_action( 'init', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter' );
function wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter( $var ) {
    return is_array( $var ) ? array_intersect( $var, array( 'current-menu-item' ) ) : '';
}

//Remove Unecessary <li> Classes
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_nav_menu_css_class' );
function my_nav_menu_css_class( $classes ) {
    $custom_classes = array();

    foreach ( $classes as $class ) {

        if ( $class == 'menu-item' ) {
            return $custom_classes;
        }
        $custom_classes[] = $class;
    }
}

//Add Custom Class to Navigation <a> Tags
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_anchor_nav_primary', 10, 3 );
function add_class_anchor_nav_primary( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    //Check for Location of Menu
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu' ) {
        // Add the Class
        $atts['class'] = 'dropdown submenu';
    }

    return $atts;
}
```

This is adding the classes to every  tag while I only need them to be on the first layer of links and not the submenu items that dropdown. Any input would be greatly appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `primary-menu` is the complete top menu so this can't work for your menu items. Try this instead:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_anchor_nav_primary', 10, 3 );
function add_class_anchor_nav_primary( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if ( (int) $item->menu_item_parent === 0 ) {
        $class         = 'dropdown submenu';
        $atts['class'] = $class;
    }

    return $atts;
}
```

This will add your class to all main links excluding the dropdown links. It works because we're checking if the given item has a parent or not. If not (=== 0), we can say, that this is a non-dropdown link. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: So this worked perfectly for my issue but it also brought another issue to light. Now the submenu <ul> has a class of "sub-menu". I need to change this to "dropdown-menu". Thoughts?

Comment: This has always the class sub-menu because it's a submenu. Do you want to change the class or is it enough to just add the class you need?

Comment: I'd like to totally change the class. I assumed this is the default class for wordpress submenus. Do I need a custom walker for this or can we change it easily in functions?

Comment: You can add another statement in our function. Please write a short ne question for this because on SO we create one question for one topic and post the link here. I'll try to add this.

Comment: Awesome, I went ahead and made another post to answer that part of the question but I can only post evey 90 minutes so I will have to wait. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RedPanda Alright, I've your code and ready to post the answer. Can you tell me the class you want instead of sub-menu?

Comment: dropdown-menu is the class I'm using for those

Comment: Okay. Go ahead in 90 minutes. I'll keep an eye on this question so you can paste the link here until it's created. Sorry that you've to wait.

Comment: By the way what is with the dropdown-toggle class in the link tag?

Comment: It is a bootstrap.min.css property. Basically it just adds animation to the dropdown menu.

Comment: Alright here we go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794525/wordpress-how-to-add-custom-class-to-submenu-ul-tags