# WordPress - How to add custom class to submenu <ul> tags

Tags: javascript, wordpress

When creating a custom WordPress menu and removing submenu classes the defaults are added back in so I just need to overwrite those with my own classes. Below is the function that works to remove the submenu class while adding custom classes to only the primary nav links.

```
//Add Custom Class to Navigation <a> Tags
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_anchor_nav_primary', 10, 3 );
function add_class_anchor_nav_primary( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if ( (int) $item->menu_item_parent === 0 ) {
        $class         = 'dropdown submenu';
        $atts['class'] = $class;
    }

    return $atts;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to modify the class of your submenu you have 2 options. The first one is to use the Walker which is used by WordPress to generate the menu. And there is solution two which I prefer:

```
add_action('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'custom_submenu_css_class');
function custom_submenu_css_class() {
    return array('dropdown-menu');
}
```

This will replace the class sub-menu with dropdown-menu. The array which get's returned can have multiple values. So if you want another class in your submenu, you can do this:

```
add_action('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'custom_submenu_css_class');
function custom_submenu_css_class() {
    return array('class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3');
}
```

Add this to your `functions.php` file. I hope it helps to reach your goals!

Comment: This wording is confusing, it would be nice if you showed solution #1 or changed the layout of your answer to be clear you are not showing solution #1